# USB Drive cannot be read in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, xubuntu, usb-drive

I have a 64 GB 3.0 ADATA USB Flash Drive. Everything was fine until few days ago I had problems writing and reading files from it, it was extremely slow or refused to write files on it... so I decided to format it on Windows, but it got stuck during the formatting process so I canceled it, now I cannot open my drive on Windows so I decided to use my Linux Partition to format it but GParted can't read it, it shows the message:  "Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb"

The command `lsblk` shows:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698,7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   650M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  99,6G  0 part /media/jorge/Windows
├─sda5   8:5    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0   300G  0 part /media/jorge/Data
├─sda7   8:7    0  24,9G  0 part 
├─sda8   8:8    0   1,9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda9   8:9    0 270,8G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1  57,8G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

So, at least it's recognized as "sdb". I can also see it on "Disks" but when I try to format it, it shows:

```
Error creating file system: Command-line `mkntfs -f -F -L "jorge" "/dev/sdb"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: `Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
'
stderr: `/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition.
mkntfs forced anyway.
Error writing to /dev/sdb: Input/output error
Error writing non-resident attribute value.
add_attr_sd failed: Input/output error
Couldn't create root directory: Input/output error
' (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I've had this drive for a year and a half or so, I've formatted it sometimes but it had always worked fine until now.